# Can't access jQuery from context.callMethod

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm trying to add the handsontable through the dart:js `context` object, but getting the error:

```
Exception: Uncaught Error: NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'jQuery'
Receiver: Instance of 'JsObject'
Arguments: ["#handsontable"]
```

My html:

```
<script src="../lib/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/jquery.handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="../lib/jquery.handsontable.full.css">
<script type="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('jquery initialized' + $('#handsontable'));
    })
</script>

<script async type="application/dart" src="propmgmt.dart"></script>
<script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

calling it thusly:

```
var hot_data = new JsObject.jsify({
    'colHeaders': colHeaders,
    'data': rows
});
print('jQuery (as \$): ${context[r'$']}');
print('jQuery: ${context['jQuery']}');

context
  .callMethod('jQuery', ['#handsontable'])
  .callMethod('handsontable', [hot_data]);
```

the "jquery initialized" doesn't show up in the console.

Comment: Does it get printed when you disable all Dart scripts?

Comment: Just another schoolboy error; I moved the jquery lib and missed the errs at the top of the console. Also, the `script` was in `head` instead of `body`.